# Inserting dynamic textbox field values to database? create mysql fields dynamically?

Tags: php, javascript

I have been finding a way to input the values of my dynamic form to my database but I'm out of ideas. I have found a solution on how to create these textboxes dynamically. The maximum is 6 textboxes named txtdatefrom0 and txtdateto0, txtdatefrom1 and txtdateto1, and so on.

Here's the php code for inserting it to the database (not working):

```
<?php
if(!mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) || !mysql_select_db($mysql_db)) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
$sets=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["num"]); 
for($loop=0;$loop<$sets;$loop++){
    $df="txtdatefrom".$loop;
    $dt="txtdateto".$loop;
    if(isset($_POST[$df]) && isset($_POST[$dt])) {
        $datefrom=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST[$df]);
        $dateto=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST[$dt]);
        $query="INSERT INTO testob (datefrom,dateto) VALUES ('$datefrom','$dateto')";
        $query_run=mysql_query($query);
    }
    else {
        echo 'Fill up all fields';
    }
}
?>
```

There are two solutions that I have in mind, either create static fields for my dynamic textboxes or automatically create fields in the database for each textbox created. Thank you for taking time reading this.

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* functions.  They're deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Static fields is the way to go.
You don't want an uncontrolled number of columns.. if things go wrong your database could look like a spaghetti pretty quick. If you have a maximum number of fields.. just create that many static fields.

Comment: Let's say if I create 2 additional textboxes, how do I insert to to my database?